# Hive - get column names

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to retrieve column names from a table and load them into another table or a text file in hive? Please let me know if we can do this

Answer (score 8):

A bit more succinct version

```
hive -S -e "SHOW COLUMNS IN database_name.table_name" > column_names.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no OOTB feature which allows this. But you could use **DESCRIBE** with **awk** to achieve that :

```
bin/hive -S -e "use default; describe demo;" | awk -F" " '{print $1}' > ~/filename.txt
```

Replace **default** and **demo** with database and table you want to operate on.

Comment: The statement "no OOTB feature" is an overstatement. [SHOW COLUMNS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowColumns) has been in Hive since version 0.10.

Comment: @JosephCottam : OOTB was mentioned to point out that there's no built in command that allows us to export column names into another table or a file.  If you still feel it to be overstated feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is by using hive.cli.print.headers=true

This is what I am using for getting the headers as comma separated. Replace *database* and *table* accordingly:

```
hive -S -e 'SET hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 0' | sed -e 's/\t/,/g' > headers.txt
```