# Just get column names from hive table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I know that you can get column names from a table via the following trick in hive:

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> select * from tablename;
```

Is it also possible to **just** get the column names from the table?

I dislike having to change a setting for something I only need once.

My current solution is the following:

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> select * from tablename;
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=false;
```

This seems too verbose and against the DRY-principle.

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the column names along with the select * output ?

Comment: why not do a describe table ??

Comment: doh! didnt find that one in the docs. describe table does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive - get column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038624/hive-get-column-names)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you simply want to see the column names this one line should provide it without changing any settings:

```
describe database.tablename;
```

However, if that doesn't work for your version of hive this code will provide it, but your default database will now be the database you are using:

```
use database;
describe tablename;
```

Comment: I got one question: will describe scan all partitions, causing HiveMetastore OOM? I encountered OOM when executing describe tablename in my case.

Comment: Thanks!, but this also gives extra info like about partition etc, how to filter only for column names any idea?

Comment: How I can add a value eg. '%INVENTORY%' to the code above to check if there is any column which contains Inventory?

Comment: Just follow the below answer, which is the more correct answer. `show columns in $table`

Comment: How do we do select statement to get all attributes as column in hive instead of using describe statement

Answer (score 71):

you could also do `show columns in $table` or see [Hive, how do I retrieve all the database's tables columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239565/hive-how-do-i-retrieve-all-the-databases-tables-columns/33154251#33154251) for access to hive metadata

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question "is it possible to **just** get the column names", as `describe` provides extra information.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate. Because it doesn't return extra information. For example, if your table has partitions,  DESCRIBE command will return some extra rows, including empty ones.

Comment: This answer requires an edit since Hive 3.0! Now ``show columns in $table`` orders the column names, possibly braking other code when the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
show columns in table_name;
```

This is simpler than use

```
describe tablename;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use `desc tablename` from Hive CLI or beeline to get all the column names. If you want the column names in a file then run the below command from the shell.

```
$ hive -e 'desc dbname.tablename;' > ~/columnnames.txt
```

where `dbname` is the name of the Hive database where your table is residing
You can find the file columnnames.txt in your root directory.

```
$cd ~
$ls
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do this is setting the below property:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
```